# How to find records which do not exist in child table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables as follows

**messages**

| id | message |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This is the first message |
| 2 | This is the second message |
| 3 | This is the third message |

**users**

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | firstuser |
| 2 | seconduser |
| 3 | thirduser |

**message_user_reads**

| id | user_id | message_id | read_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-15 12:33:13 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-11 12:33:13 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2021-02-10 12:33:13 |

From the above, I want to find out the count of messages not read by a particular user.

I have derived a query as below to solve the above puzzle but I am concerned about performance issues as messages table can have many records as time goes. Here is the query

```sql
select * from `messages` where `id` not in (select `message_id` from `message_user_reads` where `user_id` = 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

for get the message not read  you can use left join

```
select messages.* 
from `messages` m
left join message_user_reads mur on mur.message_id = m.id   
    and mur.user_id = 1
where mur.message_id is null
```

the use of left join produce better performance respect to not in

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
messages msg inner join
users usr on msg.user_id = user.id 
where 
not exists  
( 
select 1 from 
message_user_reads 
where user_id = usr.id
) 
and user.id=1
```

You will find a good explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Tip: Don't use `*` inside EXISTS. If fact, don't use `*` altogether.

Comment: And seeing as we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992, why not JOIN us?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the suggestion. I will JOIN you :D